# Icecast Server url only works on ":80"

Tags: windows, server, icecast

I am running Icecast server on Windows system, latest version, and trying to use SSL. It does work, but only when I add :80 to my URL. Some Android users say that they have problems listening to the stream, but it does work for me. I want to try to reach the server without this added :80 to the url, hopefully taht will solve listening issues (I probably do something wrong! I just don't know what).

Server URL: https://icecast.myradio.co.il:80

Audio tag Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hd3r1p29/

Icecast XML:

```
<icecast>
    <admin>hidden</admin>
    <location>earth</location>
    <limits>
        <clients>1000</clients>
        <sources>5</sources>
        <queue-size>524288</queue-size>
        <client-timeout>30</client-timeout>
        <header-timeout>15</header-timeout>
        <source-timeout>10</source-timeout>
        <!-- same as burst-on-connect, but this allows for being more
             specific on how much to burst. Most people won't need to
             change from the default 64k. Applies to all mountpoints  -->
        <burst-size>65535</burst-size>
    </limits>

    <authentication>
        <!-- Sources log in with username 'source' -->
        <source-password>hidden</source-password>
        <!-- Relays log in username 'relay' -->
        <relay-password>hidden</relay-password>

        <!-- Admin logs in with the username given below -->
        <admin-user>hidden</admin-user>
        <admin-password>hidden</admin-password>
    </authentication>

    <hostname>icecast.myradio.co.il</hostname>

    <!-- You may have multiple <listener> elements -->
    <listen-socket>
        <port>8000</port>
        <bind-address>144.76.80.253</bind-address>
        </listen-socket>
    <listen-socket>
        <port>80</port>
        <bind-address>144.76.80.253</bind-address>
        <ssl>1</ssl>
        </listen-socket>
    <fileserve>1</fileserve>
<paths>
<logdir>./log</logdir> 
<webroot>./web</webroot> 
<adminroot>./admin</adminroot>
<ssl-certificate>./ssl/icecast.pem</ssl-certificate>
<alias source="/" dest="/index.html"/> 
    </paths>

</icecast>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not normal to run HTTPS on port 80.  Normally, it's ran up on port 443.  Port 80 is where normal HTTP runs.  This is why when you use an HTTPS URL, you have to specify the port... because you're not using the standard port configuration.

Set your `<listen-socket>` with SSL enabled to use port `443`.  Change the other that's currently on port `8000` to `80`.